# Nginx match dynamic urls to the same file

Tags: nginx

I want to match all the following URLs to a file `codes.html` under `/var/www/html`?

`https://example.com/codes/ksy2ixd`

`https://example.com/codes/2shxhgw`

`https://example.com/codes/xhwhwnx`

I have tried the following

```
location ~ /codes(.*) {
      alias /var/www/html/;
      index codes.html;
```

but this keeps appending codes.html to the URL causing a redirect loop.

Comment: @RichardSmith that resolves to`https://example.com/codes/2shxhgw/codes.html` and throws a 404

Comment: Try: `root /var/www/html; try_files /codes.html =404;`

Comment: thanks @RichardSmith that worked but all the other assets are throwing 404s. I think I'm going to make the `code` a query param and handle in JS.